# How can i use for loop instead of while loop with the same answer

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
tries = 0
while tries < 4:
    deposit = input("Enter amount to deposit: ")
    try:
        deposit = int(deposit)
        if deposit < 0:
            raise "invalid output"
    except:
        print("This transaction cannot proceed. You entered amount in negative")
        tries += 1
    else:
        print("Deposited: \tPKR ", deposit)
        print("Current Balance: \tPKR %d"%(currentBalance + deposit))
        currentBalance += deposit
        print("Would you like to do any more Transaction?")
        answer = input("Enter Y for Yes and N for No: ")
        try:
            if answer.isalpha() == False:
                raise "invalid output"
        except:
            print("Your input was considered as 'N'")
            main()
print("You entered invalid input three times. Now open your account again")
main()
```

Comment: Have you tried `for tries in range (0,4):` instead?

Comment: Code-only questions are... bad.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I reformatted your code heavily: there appeared to be two instances of the same code overlapping, so I replaced it with just one instance. You should try to explain _why_ you're seeking to rewrite your code as a for loop, and what is the final goal you are trying to achieve. You can try some of the ideas suggested in the comments and edit your question with your attempt. Good luck!

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow! It's my favourite website. I will keep in mind these things you mentioned 'Praveen'. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for tries in range(0, 4):
    deposit = input("Enter amount to deposit: ")
        try:
            deposit = int(deposit)
            if deposit < 0:
                raise "invalid output"
        except:
            print("This transaction cannot proceed. You entered amount in negative")
            tries += 1
        else:
            print("Deposited: \tPKR ", deposit)
            print("Current Balance: \tPKR %d"%(currentBalance + deposit))
            currentBalance += deposit
            print("Would you like to do any more Transaction?")
            answer = input("Enter Y for Yes and N for No: ")
            try:
                if answer.isalpha() == False:
                    raise "invalid output"
            except:
                print("Your input was considered as 'N'")
                main()
```